# SQL query for customer who checked out one item before checking out another

Tags: sql

say I have a table like this:
Rental_list

| Customer | Product | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | basketball | 01-05-2020 |
| Sam | baseball | 02-15-2020 |
| Sam | soccer ball | 02-20-2020 |
| Jen | Basketball | 03-15-2020 |
| Jen | baseball | 03-29-2020 |
| James | soccer ball | 04-19-2020 |

I want a result to show me people who rented a  baseball before renting a soccer ball.
The result should be Sam, who rented a baseball on 2-15 and a soccerball on 2-20

I know if i was simply looking for the customers first purchase i could use something like
select name, min(date)
from rental_list
group by name

and i know the below would just provide the names of the two people who rented baseballs.

select name, min(date)
from rental_list
where product = 'baseball'
group by name

so how can i make it so it pulls only sam, who rented a baseball then a soccerball?

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags pls add the one back that you are actually using!

Comment: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLServer? ... please add a tag according to dbms your are using.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following^

```
  SELECT A.CUSTOMER
  FROM  Rental_list AS A
  WHERE A.Product='BASEBALL'
  AND EXISTS
   (
      SELECT 1 FROM Rental_list AS B
        WHERE A.CUSTOMER=B.CUSTOMER AND A.DATE<B.DATE AND B.PRODUCT='soccer ball'
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregating and `having`:

```
select customer
from t
group by customer
having min(case when product = 'baseball' then date end) < min(case when product = 'soccer ball' then date end);
```